# Low beams work, High beams don't .

Tags: toyota, headlight, tacoma

The car is a 2012 Tacoma pre-runner. I got in it last night and turned on the headlights. The low beams came on just fine, when I pushed the lever forward to engage the high beams, the low beams went out and all I had were weak fog light. When I return the lever back to normal the low beams come on. I looked and there is only one bulb in each headlight. Not sure what is going on?

Comment: Each bulb has 2 filaments, a low and a high, it is possible both high filaments are burned out. Also look for high beam fuses under the dash and under the hood.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suspect it's either a fuse as Moab suggested or the switch. I doubt it's the bulbs, but there is an outside chance of it being that.

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that. I will check and get back with you!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 what do you mean by "the switch"? Sorry, very car dumb over here... haha

Comment: No worries. We are all dumb until we know ... that's why we come to StackExchange :o) I meant the switch which controls the lights/hi-beams. I would *suspect* it's on the left side of the steering column? Most of them you push forward for continuous hi-beam.